# How can i optimize below query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have this complex mysql query, on a data set of a few thousand records, the performance of query degrades greatly. `*_shifted_AllocationDate` columns are computed columns of a view(`vw_transaction_details`).
How can I improve performance for it?

```
SELECT
    PointsAllocationId,
    (
        select 
            count(1) 
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId AND v.PointsAllocationId <= p.PointsAllocationId
    ) `TransactionNumberOfMember`,
    (
        select 
            count(1) 
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId 
          AND DATE(v.hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) = DATE(p.hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate)
          AND v.PointsAllocationId <= p.PointsAllocationId
    ) `TransactionNumberOfDayForMember`,
    (
        select 
            count(1) 
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId 
          AND DATE(v.AllocationDate) between DATE(TIMESTAMPADD(Day, -weekday(p.AllocationDate),p.AllocationDate)) and DATE(TIMESTAMPADD(Day, 6-weekday(p.AllocationDate),p.AllocationDate)) 
          AND v.PointsAllocationId <= p.PointsAllocationId
    ) `TransactionNumberOfWeekForMember`,
    (
        select 
            count(1)
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId 
          AND Month(v.day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) = Month(p.day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) 
          AND year(v.day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) = year(p.day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) 
          AND v.PointsAllocationId <= p.PointsAllocationId
    ) `TransactionNumberOfMonthForMember`,
    (
        select 
            count(1)
        from vw_transaction_details v
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId 
          AND year(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) = year(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) 
          AND v.PointsAllocationId <= p.PointsAllocationId
    ) `TransactionNumberOfYearForMember`
    , (select 
            count(1) 
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId) as `TotalTransactionsOfThatMember`
    , (select 
            count(1) 
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId 
          AND DATE(v.hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) = DATE(p.hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate)
      ) as `TotalTransactionsOfThatMemberOnThatDay` 
    , (select 
            count(1)
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId 
         AND  Month(v.day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) = Month(p.day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) 
         AND  year(v.day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) = year(p.day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate)) 
         as TotalTransactionsOfThatMemberOnThatMonth
    , (select 
            count(1) 
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId 
          AND DATE(v.AllocationDate) between DATE(TIMESTAMPADD(Day, -weekday(p.AllocationDate),p.AllocationDate)) and DATE(TIMESTAMPADD(Day, 6-weekday(p.AllocationDate),p.AllocationDate)) 
      ) as TotalTransactionsOfThatMemberOnThatWeek 
    , (select 
            count(1)
        from vw_transaction_details v 
        where v.DealerId = p.DealerId 
          AND year(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) = year(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate)
      ) as TotalTransactionsOfThatMemberOnThatYear
    , (select if(count(1) < 12, 0, min(x.tCount)) from (
            SELECT COUNT(1) tCount, MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) `month`, v.DealerId, YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) `year`
            FROM vw_transaction_details v
            GROUP BY MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate), v.DealerId, YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate)
        ) as x
        GROUP BY x.DealerId, x.`year`
        having x.DealerId = p.DealerId AND x.`year` =  YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate)
    ) as MinMonthlyTransaction
    ,(select max(x.tCount) from (
            SELECT COUNT(1) tCount, MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) `month`, v.DealerId, YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate) `year`
            FROM vw_transaction_details v
            GROUP BY MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate), v.DealerId, YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate)
        ) as x
        GROUP BY x.DealerId, x.`year`
        having x.DealerId = p.DealerId AND x.`year` =  YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate)
    ) as MaxMonthlyTransaction
FROM
    `vw_transaction_details` as `p`
where P.AllocationDate between P_stratDateTime and P_endDateTime
AND P.PointsAllocationId not in (
    select CorrespondingToPointAllocationId from offer_point_allocation where OfferRuleId = P_OfferId
)
Order by P.PointsAllocationId asc
LIMIT 100;
```

**Contrxt Info**

This query is being used to take out different parameters about point allocations, these parameters acts as an input to a process which performs certain actions according to these parameters. these parameter includes `total number of transaction on that day/week/month/year per dealer` and `index(1 base) of transaction on day/week/month/year per dealer`.

I have edited my query to include identity column `PointsAllocationId` in select statement. Actually it was part of original query, but i have removed all non-computed columns in an attempt to make query smaller before posting it.

**Explain Output**

```
| id |     select_type      |         table          | partitions | type |                                                                                                                                   possible_keys                                                                                                                                    |                               key                               | key_len |       ref        | rows | filtered |                    Extra                     |
|----|----------------------|------------------------|------------|------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|---------|------------------|------|----------|----------------------------------------------|
|  1 | PRIMARY              | p                      | NULL       | ref  | Ix_AllocationType,Ix_AllocationDate,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate                   | IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId                                  | 9       | const,const      |  153 |    45.99 | Using index condition; Using where           |
| 16 | UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY | offer_point_allocation | NULL       | ref  | CorrespondingToPointAllocationId_idx,Offer_Rule_OfferRuleId_idx                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | Offer_Rule_OfferRuleId_idx                                      | 4       | const            |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
| 14 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | <derived15>            | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | NULL                                                            | NULL    | NULL             |  153 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
| 15 | DERIVED              | p                      | NULL       | ref  | Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate                                     | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 9       | const,const      |  153 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 12 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | <derived13>            | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | NULL                                                            | NULL    | NULL             |  153 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
| 13 | DERIVED              | p                      | NULL       | ref  | Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate                                     | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 9       | const,const      |  153 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 11 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate         | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
| 10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate         | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  9 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate         | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  8 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate         | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate         | IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId                         | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |    33.33 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |    33.33 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |    33.33 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |    33.33 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   | p                      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IX_PointAllocation_DealerId,Ix_AllocationType,ix_allocationTypeId,ix_statustypeid,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId,IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType,ix_pointAllocation_DealerId_Status_allocationType_allocatioDate | IX_allocationType_StatusTypeId_dealerId                         | 13      | const,const,func |   57 |    33.33 | Using where; Using index                     |
```

**Here is View**

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`%` 
   SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `vw_transaction_details` AS
    SELECT 
        `p`.*,
        FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_MIN(`p`.`AllocationDate`) AS `min_shifted_AllocationDate`,
        FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_HOUR(FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_MIN(`p`.`AllocationDate`)) AS `hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate`, 
        FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_DAY(FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_HOUR(FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_MIN(`p`.`AllocationDate`))) AS `day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate`,FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_MONTH(FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_DAY(FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_HOUR(FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_MIN(`p`.`AllocationDate`)))) AS `month_day_hour_min_shifted_AllocationDate`
FROM
    `pointsallocation` `p`
WHERE
    ((`p`.`AllocationType` = 2401)
        AND (`p`.`StatusTypeId` = 2501))
ORDER BY `p`.`DealerId`
```

and functions `FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_*` are somthing like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `FN_ADD_OFFER_VW_DAY`(
 P_time DATETIME
) RETURNS datetime
return date_add(P_time, interval @offer_vw_day day)
```

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you about the execution plan?

Comment: I would add in the actual query the VIEW is based upon.  There might be a better way to optimize  knowing the origin of its data / results.

Comment: Additionally, it looks like a strange purpose query.  It LOOKS like you are trying to do a compare of a roll-up of all values  per dealer for all allocation points prior to the current.  Can you please edit your question (vs comments added) and clarify WHAT the output will be used for, what the numbers should be reflecting to give better context than just... I have a slow query.  For this and future posts, clarity of context can significantly help others trying to offer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, I recommend avoiding repeated correlated subqueries, and instead use conditional aggregation.

The original query is a bit strange, returning every row from `vw_transaction_details` but not including any identifier, or any other information, from the row, just counts of other rows.

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT v.dealerid

     , COUNT(1) AS `TotalTransactionsOfThatMember`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     v.pointsallocationid                             <= p.pointsallocationid
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TransactionNumberOfMember`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     v.pointsallocationid <= p.pointsallocationid
                 AND DATE(v.hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)           = DATE(p.hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TransactionNumberOfDayForMember`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     v.pointsallocationid                             <= p.pointsallocationid
                 AND DATE(v.allocationdate) >= DATE(p.allocationdate) + INTERVAL 0-WEEKDAY(p.allocationdate) DAY
                 AND DATE(v.allocationdate) <= DATE(p.allocationdate) + INTERVAL 6-WEEKDAY(p.AllocationDate) DAY
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TransactionNumberOfWeekForMember`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     v.pointsallocationid                             <= p.pointsallocationid
                 AND MONTH(v.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)      = MONTH(p.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)
                 AND  YEAR(v.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)      =  YEAR(p.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TransactionNumberOfMonthForMember`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     v.pointsallocationid                             <= p.pointsallocationid
                 AND YEAR(v.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)       = YEAR(p.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TransactionNumberOfYearForMember`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     v.pointsallocationid                             <= p.pointsallocationid
                 AND DATE(v.hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)           = DATE(p.hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TotalTransactionsOfThatMemberOnThatDay`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     MONTH(v.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)      = MONTH(p.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)
                 AND  YEAR(v.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)      =  YEAR(p.day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TotalTransactionsOfThatMemberOnThatMonth`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     DATE(v.allocationdate) >= DATE(p.allocationdate) + INTERVAL 0-WEEKDAY(p.allocationdate) DAY
                 AND DATE(v.allocationdate) <= DATE(p.allocationdate) + INTERVAL 6-WEEKDAY(p.allocationdate) DAY
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TotalTransactionsOfThatMemberOnThatWeek`

     , COUNT(IF(
                     YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate)
       ,1,NULL)) AS `TotalTransactionsOfThatMemberOnThatYear`

     , IF(
         COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT( v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate ,'%Y-%m') < 12
         , 0
         , LEAST (
             COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  1 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  2 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  3 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  4 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  5 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  6 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  7 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  8 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  9 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = 10 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = 11 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = 12 ,1,NULL))
           )
         )
       ) AS `MinMonthlyTransaction`

     , GREATEST(
             COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  1 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  2 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  3 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  4 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  5 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  6 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  7 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  8 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) =  9 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = 10 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = 11 ,1,NULL))
           , COUNT(IF( YEAR(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = YEAR(p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) AND MONTH(v.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate) = 12 ,1,NULL))
       ) AS `MaxMonthlyTransaction`

  FROM vw_transaction_details p
  JOIN vw_transaction_details v
    ON v.dealerid = p.dealerid
    -- anti-join
  LEFT
  JOIN offer_point_allocation opa
    ON opa.offerruleid   = P_OfferId
   AND opa.correspondingtopointallocationid = p.pointsallocationid
 WHERE opa.offerruleid IS NULL
   AND p.pointsallocationid IS NOT NULL
   AND p.allocationdate >=      P_stratDateTime
   AND p.allocationdate <=      P_endDateTime
 GROUP
    BY p.uniqueid
     , p.pointsallocationid
     , p.allocationdate
     , p.day_hour_min_shifted_allocation_date
     , p.month_day_hour_min_shifted_allocationdate
     , v.dealerid
 ORDER
    BY p.pointsallocationid ASC
```

Comment: I was able to run your script after commenting `MinMonthlyTransaction` and removing `p.uniqueid` from `Group by` as `pointsallocationid` is identity column, I run this query on small set of records (153 rows from view) and it took >12 sec in comparison to >2 sec of old query. I have also updated my question with few more details.